# Binding two Comboboxes and keeping them synchronized in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am developing a Point of Sale software in Vb.net. I want to render the functionality which binds the Comboboxes and keep them synchronized. For eg: ComboBox1 displays the "Book_Name" and Combobox2 Displays the "Book_Code". As soon as the "Book_Name" is selected in Combobox1 by the user,  Combobox2 must automatically display the corresponding "Book_Code". 
Can anyone suggest me a programming code to implement this functionality in VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

You would simply bind both controls to the same data source, e.g.

```
myBindingSource.DataSource = myDataTable

With ComboBox1
    .DisplayMember = "BookName"
    .ValueMember = "BookId"
    .DataSource = myBindingSource
End With

With ComboBox2
    .DisplayMember = "BookCode"
    .ValueMember = "BookId"
    .DataSource = myBindingSource
End With
```

Comment: "myBindingSource.DataSource" is a read only property ? How can I assign "myDataTable" to it? @ jmcilhinney

Comment: No, the `DataSource` property of a `BindingSource` is not read-only.  I don't know what you did that led you to that conclusion but it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind both comboboxes to the same [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) instance. The BindingSource has its own DataSource property set to your DataTable instance or to your own class for a list of Books

Suppose you have a class for a Book defined as

```
Public Class Book

    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Title As String 
    Public Property Code As String
End Class
```

Now your comboboxes could be binded in this way

```
' Initialize your data -> (or load from db a DataTable)
Dim bks = New List(Of Book)()
Dim b = New Book() With {.Code = "123", .Title = "ABC", .ID = 1}
bks.Add(b)
b = New Book() With {.Code = "456", .Title = "DEF", .ID = 2}
bks.Add(b)

' Create and initialize the BindingSource instance
Dim bs = New BindingSource()
bs.DataSource = bks

' Set the first combo to display the Title
cbo1.ValueMember = "ID"
cbo1.DisplayMember = "Title"
cbo1.DataSource = bs

' Set the second combo to display the code
cbo2.ValueMember = "ID"
cbo2.DisplayMember = "Code"
cbo2.DataSource = bs
```

Now the two comboboxes are synchronized and both display the same item because at the SelectedIndexChange event the BindingSource keeps them on the same record

This example uses for simplicity a custom class. If you want to use a DataTable then set the DataTable as the DataSource of the BindingSource and change the [DisplayMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ValueMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the two combos to the column name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "Book_Name"
            ComboBox2.Text = "Book Code: 1982637"
        Case "Something On ComboBox1"
            ComboBox2.Text = "Something On ComboBox2"
            'Etc.
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the items of the two Comboboxes have the same order you could keep them synchronized by binding the selected index.

Like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox2.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```